# How do I stop the Main Panel values from changing until I click the Update button?

Tags: r, shiny

I add an Update Order button, and I want the order values do not change until the Update button is pressed. In other words, how do I stop the Main Panel values from changing until I click the Update button?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it inside an `observeEvent`. Now everytime the button refresh is pressed, the text will appear in the ui.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
  output$fruit = renderText(isolate(input$fruitchoice))
  output$amt = renderText(isolate(input$amt))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: No, my friend, it works only the first time, after that when I select other fruits or words, the UI also changes ( I don't need to pressed 'Update'.)

Comment: I forgot to add  `isolate()`. Sorry!

Comment: That works now, Thank you so much!!!!